# Problems with relative "axis cs:" coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Please behold this MWE (`compat` is at 1.13, so by default the coordinates are in `axis cs:`):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
     \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1500,   
        ymin=60, ymax=100,
        axis y line* = right,
        axis x line = none,
        clip mode = individual,
    ]
        %\addplot [domain=0:1500] {97-x/150};
        \addplot [domain=0:1500] {x/15};
        \draw [green, <-] (600, 93) -- ++(0,-1.5);
        \draw [red,  <-] (600, 93) -- (600, 93-1.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two `draw` commands executes perfectly and they give the same arrow, so you really see just one:

[image]

If you now comment out the `\addplot` and use the previous one, i.e, like this:

```
    \addplot [domain=0:1500] {97-x/150};
    %\addplot [domain=0:1500] {x/15};
```

the relative coordinates `\draw` goes astray:

[image]

Where is my fault? Is that relative movements are not supposed to work in `axis cs:`? Why it depends on the previous plot?

Comment: You have to use the `axis direction cs` for relatve positions: `\draw [green, <-] (600, 93) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1.5);`.

Comment: By the way, I found it --- it's in chapter 4.17.1 of the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`axis cs` allows only absolute position. If you need relative positions you have to use the `axis direction cs`:

```
\draw [green, <-] (600, 93) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1.5);
```

For more information see section "4.17.1 Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements" in the documentation of pgfplots.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
     \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1500,   
        ymin=60, ymax=100,
        axis y line* = right,
        axis x line = none,
        clip mode = individual,
    ]
        \addplot [domain=0:1500] {97-x/150};
        %\addplot [domain=0:1500] {x/15};
        \draw [green, <-] (600, 93) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-1.5);
        \draw [red,  <-] (600, 93) -- (600, 93-1.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]