# draw command in pgfplot axis not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to draw a radius in circle as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align={left},
    grid, grid style=dashed,
    xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
    ytick={0,0.2,...,1.2},
    xtick={0,0.2,...,1.2},
    extra y ticks={0.5},
    extra x ticks={0.5},
    axis lines = middle,
    set layers,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}, 
    x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
    y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
    x tick label style={
        tick label style={rotate=60},
        anchor=east
    },
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
    },
    axis equal,
    ]
    \node[fill,circle,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0] at (axis cs:0.5,0.5) {};
    \draw[line width=1pt] (axis cs:0.5,0.5) circle (0.5);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) -- ++(0.5,0);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the unit sounds like not as expected:
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `\draw (axis cs:0.5,0.5) -- (axis cs:1,0.5);`? Do you have any objections to using a newer version of pgfplots, where this is not necessary?

Comment: I think you need `axis direction cs` for relative coordinates, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332553/problems-with-relative-axis-cs-coordinates-in-pgfplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of `pgfplots`. So you need to prepend coordinates with `axis cs:`, as you did for the circle. Relative coordinates are even more tricky because `(axis cs:0,0)` may not be at `(0,0)` of the ambient `tikzpicture`, see [Torbjørn's link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332553/problems-with-relative-axis-cs-coordinates-in-pgfplots). However, I would like to argue that in this case the advantage of using relative coordinates is, at best, minimal. So maybe, assuming you wish to keep the old compatibility mode,

```
\draw (axis cs:0.5,0.5) -- (axis cs:1,0.5);
```

is the easiest way to go.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align={left},
    grid, grid style=dashed,
    xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
    ytick={0,0.2,...,1.2},
    xtick={0,0.2,...,1.2},
    extra y ticks={0.5},
    extra x ticks={0.5},
    axis lines = middle,
    set layers,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}, 
    x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
    y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
    x tick label style={
        tick label style={rotate=60},
        anchor=east
    },
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
    },
    axis equal,
    ]
    \node[fill,circle,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0] at (axis cs:0.5,0.5) {};
    \draw[line width=1pt] (axis cs:0.5,0.5) circle[radius=0.5];
    % or circle[x radius=\x1,y radius=\y1];
    \draw (axis cs:0.5,0.5) -- (axis cs:1,0.5) node[midway,above]{$r$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]