# How to coordinate shift in axis coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal, ymin=-10,ymax=17,xmin=-10,xmax=30]
        \draw[->] ([shift=(-150:0)]0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should be an arrow from `(0,0)` to `(1,0)`, but it is actually from some random coordinate to `(1,0)`. It looks like maybe the coordinate shift takes it out of the `axis` coordinates and into the `tikzpicture` coordinates. How to prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post complete, compilable fragments. BTW, if you do not want the shift, why do you add the `shift` keyword?

Comment: That is just to demonstrate that the `shift` changes the meaning of the coordinate before any shift is applied.

Comment: Not sure yet, but: `shift` uses relative coordinates, so you should say `\draw[->] ([shift={(axis direction cs:-1,0)}]0,0) -- (1,0);` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332603/38080) — I am not sure if you have any relative polar cs available, I do not think there is.

Comment: That is good for a Cartesian shift, but a direct polar shift is desired. I can compute it I guess, no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You need units:

```
\draw[->] ([shift=(-150:0cm)]0,0) -- (1,0);
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but it may  be better/more consistent `\draw[->] ([shift=(-150pt:0pt)]0,0) -- (1,0);` ?